# about onMeasure and onLayout for FrameLayout

Tags: android

when i Override onMeasure  extends FrameLayout ,and Override onLayout to addview
an imageview ,but this imageview not visable
[image]

but the blue background has display now , layout like this , who can help me, 
why call addview is ineffective

```
<com.farsunset.lvxin.component.LoginBallsView
            android:id="@+id/balls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

Comment: do you know how many times `onLayout` can be called? do you want to add a new `ImageView` each time?

Comment: when onmeasue done now can be call onlayout only once

Comment: run [this](http://pastebin.com/6V44SrmG) then